# How to customize x axis labels in Apex chart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I have financial daily data (1980 to 2023) for different date ranges (1Day ,5 Day,1 Month ,3 Month,6Month,1Year, 5Year, All)
These data show on chart according to selected date range and formatting are different for each date range. I want format x axis label like this:

1 Day

show current date and then show each hour on x axis.

[image]

3 month

Get start date of Monday then get date after 2 week

[image]

All

[image]

For these formatting I have one function that takes array dates from data as argument and return array of dates that I want to show on x axis. Is it possible to use this function in apex chart?  If yes, then how to use this function. Please suggest.
If no, then please suggest me how to do this kind of formatting in Apex chart.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: try this:
```
chart.updateOptions({
  xaxis: {
    categories: newCategories
  }
});
```